# Error "'page' is missing in prop validation" even though I have it defined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-proptypes

Am I missing something?  I'm defining the 'page' prop and I'm not sure why it's still giving me this error.. I'm not sure if i'm missing something obvious or if this is a bug?

> ⚠  44:9  'page' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types

```
const propTypes = {
  eActions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  entities: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  page: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  pages: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  sActions:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  singular: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

function renderPage( props ) {
  let { page } = props;  // LINE 44 HERE
  ...
}

const PlaylistPage = SortableElement((props) => {
  return (
    renderPage( props )
  );
});

PlaylistPage.propTypes = propTypes;

export default PlaylistPage;
```

Comment: What is SortableElement? You are doing the propType check on SortableElement.

Comment: If renderPage is a stateless functional component, then you should do `renderPage.propTypes = { ... }`. By the way, components should be named using the CapitalCase naming convention.

Comment: SortableElement is something from a library I'm using for drag and drop https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc

Comment: @nbkhope renderPage is just supposed to be a function that i'm using in my stateless functional component "PlaylistPage".. am I doing this wrong?

Comment: @nbkhope defining propTypes for that function worked thank you.  though I think I'm doing something wrong in my formatting if I'm having to declare propTypes for what's supposed to be just a function..

Comment: Nope, it might look a bit weird at first but that's basically how you're supposed to do it.

Comment: @BenHare thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment to the question worked for you. Here is my answer version.

You are actually checking the propTypes of `SortableElement`. I am assuming it is a third-party (high-order?) component.

If `renderPage` is a stateless functional component, then you should do the propTypes check on that component:

```
renderPage.propTypes = { ... }
```

Because that is the component that receives `page` and all the other props.